# using ax instead of dx with interrupt 21

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, 16-bit, real-mode

In the following code

```
data segment
    ; add your data here!
    num db 0,0,0,0 
    sum db 0 
    str db "Sum is : $"
ends

stack segment
    dw   128  dup(0)
ends

code segment
start:
; set segment registers:
    mov ax, data
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax

    ;;read array from input     
    mov cx,4;set loop counter
    L1:
    mov ah,7;interupt 7 use for reading character without echo
    int 21h  
    mov num,al;mov al to num 
    add sum,al
    inc num;nex element
    LOOP L1 
    sub num,4;go to first position
    ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

    ;;show sum  
    lea dx,str;;-----------------I'm changing this line-----------------------
    mov ah,9;interupt 9 for writing string
    int 21h 
    ;;;;;;;;;;;           

    mov ax, 4c00h ; exit to operating system.
    int 21h    
ends

end start ; set entry point and stop the assembler.
```

if I change  dx to ax

```
lea dx,str --> lea ax,str
```

The out put become `1  'Sum is`
But if I use `lea ax,str` It is correct > `Sum is :`

I cant figure out the reason !

Why changing dx to ax causes the wrong output ?

Comment: What do you know about the interrupt used to print a string?  In particular, how do you tell it what string to print?

Comment: @ScottHunter tnx I found the reason after reading this link :) http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html       ------- Interupt use dx register for writing to output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not randomly exchange AX for DX. The DOS function to print a string uses DX and that's final!
From your program I see that nothing you do with inputting and summing has any effect on the string you display afterwards.
If with your assembler `mov num,al` changes the content at the address of 'num' then the line `inc num;nex element` will certainly not advance to the next element but rather augment the content by 1. The same applies to `sub num,4;go to first position`